# Missing executor CloudWatch logs for AWS Glue version 2.0 ETL job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-glue-spark

I am running `glueetl` (Glue version 2.0) job using Python with the below configuration for logging. I have [continuous logging enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html).

I get `INFO` entries from the driver present in `/aws-glue/jobs/output` log group, however there are no `INFO` entries present for executors, neither in `/aws-glue/jobs/output` nor in `/aws-glue/jobs/logs-v2` log groups.

I ran experiment where setting log level to `WARN` and logging `WARN` statements made the `WARN` entries be present, but in `/aws-glue/jobs/error` log group.

```
import sys
import logging

MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger(getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])["JOB_NAME"])

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```